# Wordpress Dashboard keeps showing page not found error

Tags: wordpress

I have tried logging in to my wordpress dashboard. But after loggin in, everytime I click on any tab like "menu, or try to add new plugin or new page, it always takes me back my live site saying "page not found"
I have tried update the .htaccess folder, but yet still
I have disabled the plugins and themes but yet still the same issues

Please help

Comment: Live website or localhost website? NGINX or Apache?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.